# Linear Reactivity Model

Tags: nuclear-engineering

The Linear Reactivity Model seems to be a model for the consumption of the nuclear fuel management.It is a powerful tool to estimate the main performances in function It is a very simple way to choose different types of nuclear fuel to reach a goal of combustion rate.

I would like to know if someone could explain how this model works:

- Its hypotheses
- Its usefulness (the results of this model)

Answer (score 1):

You could always read the book:

Driscoll, Downar, and Pilat, "The Linear Reactivity Model for Nuclear Fuel Management," American Nuclear Society (1991).
ISBN 978-0894480355

Note that this model is considered out-of-date and is not used in production work.

Comment: Why is this model out-of-date? What replaces it currently?